# Xcode 4.5 Enterprise signing issue (worked in Xcode 4.3.3)

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning, xcode4.5

I've recently updated my Xcode on my MBP to 4.5 (first picture), and now all my identities say "from '(null)'" in them when I try to sign for enterprise distribution. I tried to go ahead and sign it and distribute it but the install failed. I went back to my iMac to sign the archive that way with Xcode 4.3.3 (bottom picture) and it signed and installed just fine. Any idea how I can get my identities right in 4.5? I was able to sign and distribute on my MBP before the update to 4.5, btw.

Thanks.

[image: Xcode 4.5]
[image: Xcode 4.3.3]

Answer (score 1):

If you havnt already refresh Xcode's auto-provisioning profiles, you may try

Xcode -> organizer button -> devices -> Library (provisioning profiles) -> right bottom "Refresh"

**suggestion #2: (edit)**

Did you happen to create a new mbp user account which causes "keychain access" to re-generate a separate set of keychain?

```
Try open up "keychain access",  
  with left sidebar :
      Keychains->"Login"
      Category ->"Certificates"
```

Do you see the private keys associated with the certs you are attempting to codesign with? ie: there should be a little triangle, click on that, and its private key should show up.

If is not there, you can try re-import the private keys from your other mac. Good luck!

**suggestion #3: (edit)**

Last time I had that (NULL) problem, I just deleted all provisioning profiles in organizer and do a "refresh" and everything was back in order.

I think my master cert expired and I renewed/revoked it, then (NULL) starting to appear.

Anyhow, good luck!

Comment: RE: Suggestion #2. Still no luck. I tried exporting all the keys from my iMac to my MBP, still nothing. Thanks for your continued help